# How to use route name while testing mojolicious application?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have read [Test::Mojo](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Test/Mojo) but do not find how to use route name while application testing:

```
$t->get_ok( 'list_users' )->status_is( 302 )->location_is( 'auth_login' );
```

Where `list_users` and `auth_login` are:

```
$r->get( '/login' )->to( 'auth#login' )->name( 'auth_login' );
$r->get( '/users' )->to( 'user#index' )->name( 'list_users' );
```

I seems to me it will be very handy if `*_ok` will count given string same as `redirect_to` does. **VOTEUP** if this looks good for feature request to you too.

As work around this problem I try to use `url_for` without success:

```
$t->url_for( 'list_users' );
#Can't locate object method "url_for" via package "Test::Mojo"
```

How can I get route path by its name from test script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Test::Mojo::Role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Mojo::WithRoles) as adviced by Sebastian Riedel:

```
package Test::Mojo::Role::MyRole;

use Role::Tiny;
use Test::More;

sub _build_ok {
    my( $self, $method, $url ) =  ( shift, shift, shift );

    if( my $route =  $t->app->routes->lookup( 'list_users' ) ) {
        $url =  $route->render;
    }

    local $Test::Builder::Level = $Test::Builder::Level + 1;
    return $self->_request_ok( $self->ua->build_tx( $method, $url, @_ ), $url );
}



sub location_is {
  my( $t, $url, $desc ) =  @_;

  if( my $route =  $t->app->routes->lookup( 'list_users' ) ) {
      $url =  $route->render;
  }
  $desc //=  "Location: $url";

  local $Test::Builder::Level =  $Test::Builder::Level + 1;
  return $t->success( is($t->tx->res->headers->location, $url, $desc) );
}


#myapp.t

use Test::Mojo::WithRoles 'MyRole';
our $t =  Test::Mojo::WithRoles->new( 'MyApp' );

$t->get_ok( 'list_users' )->status_is( 302 )->location_is( 'auth_login' );
```

**UPD**

That is better to do reverse: try to get route name from location and compare it to expected result

Comment: You shouldn't overload private methods, they can and may be changed without notice even in a minor version.

Comment: @JoelBerger; Yes, but in this case I should overload `get_ok`, `post_ok` etc. Is there workaround to do not overload private method?

Comment: I'd probably make a new one called something like `request_ok` or `route_ok` and have it take a method as its first argument. Otherwise yes, you would do best to explicitly overload all the methods that you are changing.

Comment: Also, building a controller just to call `url_for` could be replaced by talking to the app's router instance directly

Comment: @JoelBerger Thanks, I have found that: `$t->app->routes->lookup( $url )->render`

Answer (score 0):

We may `build_controller` to call `url_for`:

```
$t->app->build_controller->url_for( 'list_users' )
```